# Why am I getting a 404 error on cropper.js files in ASP.Net despite them being exactly where the program is looking for them?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cropperjs

When trying to import [cropper.js](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs) into my ASP.Net project, I copied and pasted the sample code given to implement it. However, whenever the page is loaded, I get a series of 404 errors stemming from the main cropper.js file, saying the other javascript files were not found. I have ensured they are located in Scripts/cropperjs/src/js, which is where the 404 error is saying it originated. What do I need to do to get these files to be recognized?

here is the exact code I have on the page:

```
<script type="module">
    import 'cropperjs/dist/cropper.css';
    import Cropper from 'cropper.js';

    const image = document.getElementById('cropperJS');
    const cropper = new Cropper(image, {
        aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
        crop(event) {
            console.log(event.detail.x);
            console.log(event.detail.y);
            console.log(event.detail.width);
            console.log(event.detail.height);
            console.log(event.detail.rotate);
            console.log(event.detail.scaleX);
            console.log(event.detail.scaleY);
        },
    });
</script>
```

Comment: could you please share your code?
The part where you have inserted the link to the JS.

Comment: @NicolaBiada done, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have added the following lines to your `<head>` section ?

```html
<link  href="/path/to/cropper.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/path/to/cropper.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried that, but then I get the following errors: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
Upload:1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "cropperjs/dist/cropper.css". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

Comment: You don't need the import if you are on pure asp.net.
Look at this example:
https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs/blob/main/docs/examples/crop-a-round-image.html

you need only to add reference to the JS and CSS on file system.

Comment: I have tried that as well, but then I get the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` and if I switch the imported script type to module I am back to getting all the 404 errors.

Comment: alright, I had to create a new repository because the one holding the whole project has a lot of extra things and I just wanted to both streamline this and keep some info private. This has just the bare minimum to see the problems I'm having. The relevant page is Upload.aspx, but I said the default page to automatically redirect to it so you can just load the solution and run it. Here's the link: [link](https://github.com/eshilo-draper/cropperError)